# Why is WKWebView not opening a telephone link in ios 9?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, ios10, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView that loads a webpage with some telephone links on the webpage.

Currently i have this code to handle clicks to those links.

```
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.request.url?.scheme == "tel" {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(navigationAction.request.url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(navigationAction.request.url!)
        }
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        return
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

This works fine on any device with ios 10 installed, i am prompted with an alert box asking to either cancel or make a call. but on ios 9 devices the telephone app screen flashes (no prompt) and it nothing happens after.

Answer (score 5):

Key concepts before proceed :

> By default, a web view automatically converts telephone numbers that appear in web content to Phone links. When a Phone link is tapped, the Phone app launches and dials the number. The **tel** URL scheme is used to launch the Phone app on iOS devices and initiate dialing of the specified phone number.

from the html side the web page showing phone numbers must be like this :

```html
<body>
     <!-- Then use phone links to explicitly create a link. -->
     <p>A phone number: <a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a></p>
     <!-- Otherwise, numbers that look like phone numbers are not links. -->
     <p>Not a phone number: 408-555-5555</p>
</body>
```

After this short preamble, theres two behaviour for WKWebView , one for iOS 9 and other for iOS 10 and later.

on iOS 10 Apple introduced a property called **dataDetectorTypes** on **WKWebViewConfiguration** and by default this property have the value *WKDataDetectorTypeNone* wich  means that does not detect nothing. So in the case you want to detect phone numbers and links (just an example) the configuration for WKWebView would look like this (suppose you have a variable **_webView** of type **WKWebView**):

```
    WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [WKWebViewConfiguration new];
    if ([configuration respondsToSelector:@selector(dataDetectorTypes)]) {
        configuration.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink | UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
    }

    _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:configuration];
```

with this configuration your webView will be able to handle everything under the hood.

Now on  9 > iOS < 10  (iOS between 9 and 10) your delegate decision handler would look like this :

```
    - (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {

     if ([navigationAction.request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"tel"]){

            [UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:navigationAction.request.URL];

            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);

        }else {
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
        }

    }
```

and this will open the phone app. Keep in mind that:

> iOS 10.3 and later displays an alert and requires user confirmation
>   before dialing. (When this scenario occurs in versions of iOS prior to
>   10.3, iOS initiates dialing without further prompting the user and does not display an alert, although a native app can be configured to
>   display its own alert.

Please do not follow any instruction talking about URL scheme whitelist , this is another story that apple introduce on iOS 9, but this is when you need to declare url scheme handlers, for now the tel scheme is handled by iOS.

Hope this help.

Comment: worked fine for me, i combined this with : https://gist.github.com/dakeshi/d8e69e4ba50b31211d94

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4:**

```
 webView.navigationDelegate = self
 webView.configuration.dataDetectorTypes = [.link, .phoneNumber]

extension PDFWebViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if let requestUrl = navigationAction.request.url, requestUrl.scheme == "tel" {
            UIApplication.shared.open(requestUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            decisionHandler(.cancel)

        } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }

}
```